# Hide div that when clicked outside of that opens when link is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div on my site that is display:none by default and display:inline when the user clicks a link. What I'd like to do now is hide the div when the user clicks outside of it.

This is a common problem, as lots of people have asked about it, however all the solutions I've tried seem to be buggy. Oftentimes I'll click the link and the div will only show briefly before disappearing on its own.

Here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $("#listing-new").hide(); //hides as soon as it's ready

   $("#list-item-btn").click(function(){
      $("#listing-new").show();
   });

  $(document).mouseup(function (e)
{
    var container = $("#listing-new");

    if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
        && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
    {
        container.hide();
    }
});
 });
```

What should I do? As I said, I'd like to be able to click on a link, show the div, then hide the div again when the user clicks outside of it.

Answer (score 0):

Check "onblur", this is called when a Object was selected/active and then deselected.

Example in HTML
`<div onBlur="disable()">`

Answer (score 0):

here you go:

```
$("#listing-new").hide();

$(document).on('click',function(e){
    if (!$('#listing-new').is(e.target) && $('#listing-new').has(e.target).length === 0 && !$('#list-item-btn').is(e.target) && $('#list-item-btn').has(e.target).length === 0){
        $("#listing-new").hide();
        }
    else{
        $("#listing-new").show();
        }
});
```

**[The Working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7u53a/)**

Comment: Now it works but only if you tap the link. If you click it with the left mouse button the problem persists.

Comment: I don't get what you mean, check out the demo, isn't that what you need?

Comment: do you want the div to hide when you click the anchor again?

Comment: Your code works if I remove the first line, but then the div is visible on page load. I want the div to be hidden when the page is loaded, and only reveal itself once the anchor is clicked. 

With your current code if I click the link then the div just flashes and disappears again.

Comment: works fine for me, I can't get it to reveal the bug you're facing, check it with another browser and see if it still consists!

Comment: P.S. if the div has `display:none;` in the CSS, then it will not be visible on page load!